# Arrange "pretty form" in (R)yacas

Tags: r, yacas

I have this expression:

```
"98/25 * x1^3 * x2  +  28/5 * x1^2 * x2^2  +  98/25 * x1 * x2^3"
```

When I apply `PrettyForm` with Ryacas, I get:

```
cat(yac_str("PrettyForm(98/25 * x1^3 * x2  +  28/5 * x1^2 * x2^2  +  98/25 * x1 * x2^3)"))

            3     2          2     3          
x2 * 98 * x1    x2  * 28 * x1    x2  * 98 * x1
------------- + -------------- + -------------
     25               5               25
```

I would prefer to have the numbers in each term at first position, and, if possible, to have `x1` before `x2`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a solution for this specific case, then the following code below works for me. I just changed the order of the variables in the equation.

```
cat(yac_str("PrettyForm(x1^3*x2*298/25  +  x1^2 * x2^2 * 28/5  +  x1*x2^3* 98/25)"))
```

[image].

Comment: Good to know that, but the expression is returned by a package. (+1) nevertheless. This is a package of mine, I will see what I can do.

Comment: Adding parentheses also seems to work:  `"98/25 * (x1^3 * x2)  +  28/5 * (x1^2 * x2^2)  +  98/25 * (x1 * x2^3)"`